# Request had insufficient authentication scopes. & ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[Here is error showing in network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvDAi.png)

[Here is javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9qBj.png)

I had already tried all possibility but no work for me.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}


{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "youtube.api.v3.V3DataChannelService.List",
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

getting this error in request had insufficient authentication scopes in network and in console getting error The request is missing a valid API key.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).